# How to change and save mouse settings?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, settings

My cursor got all jumpy lately and I want to lower touchpad sensitivity, how can I do it? Mouse&Touchpad menu allows me to make changes but doesn't save them after I close its window. And there's no discernible change.

Also, where is the option to disable mouse/touchpad acceleration. Do I need to edit Xorg.conf and reboot like it's 2002?

I'm on a regular Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity.

Answer (score 2):

Try `gpointing-device-settings` from the software center.

If that doesn't expose the needed features, use `synclient` in a terminal window. For example, to reduce the acceleration, use 
`synclient AccelFactor=XXX`, where XXX is a number such as 0.144509 or whatever suites the touchpad.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad" You can choose the sensitivity, the clickers (left and right) and others.